# Movement on click boolean altering beetwen players not working Java

Tags: java

So I tried everything that came to mind.
Researched it in Google - implemented solutions to similar issues.

I have a boolean "ruch", it's supposed to switch between players every time mouse is clicked. Sadly, after it switches to the second player, it never switches back to the first one.
I am new to both java and stackoverflow, so I would very much appreciate some help.

```
boolean ruch;

@FXML
private void onCellClick(MouseEvent e) {
    Node source = (Node) e.getSource();
    Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
    Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
    if (!ruch) {
        ruch = true;
        transition.setNode(group);
        transition.setToX((colIndex.intValue() * 100));
        transition.setToY((rowIndex.intValue() * 100));
        animation = transition;
        animation.play();
    } else {
        ruch = false;
        transition.setNode(group2);
        if (colIndex.intValue() == 3 && rowIndex.intValue() == 3) {
            transition.setToX(200);
            transition.setToY(200);
        } else if (colIndex.intValue() == 4 && rowIndex.intValue() == 5) {
            transition.setToX(300);
            transition.setToY(200);
        } else {
            transition.setToX((colIndex.intValue() * 100));
            transition.setToY((rowIndex.intValue() * 100));
        }
        animation = transition;
        animation.play();
    }
    ruch = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after if else  it always set group2 (player2)
put transition.setNode(group2) in else block.

```
   private void onCellClick(MouseEvent e) {
    Node source = (Node) e.getSource();
    Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
    Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
    if (!ruch) {
        ruch = true;
        transition.setNode(group);
        transition.setToX((colIndex.intValue() * 100));
        transition.setToY((rowIndex.intValue() * 100));
        animation = transition;
        animation.play();
    } else{
       ruch = false;
       transition.setNode(group2);
       if (colIndex.intValue() == 3 && rowIndex.intValue() == 3) {
           transition.setToX(200);
           transition.setToY(200);
        } else if (colIndex.intValue() == 4 && rowIndex.intValue() == 5) {
           transition.setToX(300);
           transition.setToY(200);
        } else {
           transition.setToX((colIndex.intValue() * 100));
           transition.setToY((rowIndex.intValue() * 100));
        }
        animation = transition;
        animation.play();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sadly this changes nothing. Only one player now moves.

Answer (score 0):

You set ruch to false on the bottom, so every time the you finish a click the boolean will always be false which I assume would be the second player. Maybe that is why you can't switch back to the first?

Comment: If I delete ruch = false; from the bottom it will be stuck on the first player permanently.

Comment: Your else statement after the first "if" is missing some brackets, maybe that's effecting the execution of your program

Comment: Nah, sadly that's not that either... I'm getting really desperate

Comment: I still don't think the ruch = false in the end is necessary, there might be a chance that you are setting ruch = true somewhere else in your code that is causing you to be stuck on the first player. Maybe when you first instantiate the Boolean

Comment: It's called without a value - boolean ruch; and the whole code that is supposed to alternate players is pasted. ruch is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a syntax error? if ruch does not have a value the first if statement would generate an error. You have to initialize a Boolean before you can compare it

Comment: Would it be possible if you paste your whole code? I have to head out in a bit but would love to help out if I can later today in a few hours.

Comment: Just added the whole relevant part. Thank you so much for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class mouseListener implements MouseListener {    
    boolean roch = true;
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

        if (!roch){
            System.out.println("I am player2");
            roch = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am player1");
            roch = false;
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {   
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }
}
```

Not sure if this helps, but this is something I made that might solve your problem, I have a mouse listener that tracks my mouse click, and the "public void mouseClick changes the player

Comment: I think it won't work since it's JavaFX and this implements awt. Tried it a few ways and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Well I am honestly not sure what the problem is, I guess you could try print out roch before and during your if structures to see what it is "System.out.println("\roch");" This way you can keep tracking the boolean and see where it is changed to get you stuck in 1 player. You could also try having it return a boolean and every time this method its called, feed it roch through a parameter